# Data Annotations number length

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to make a validation for number attribute with 4 digits(length).How i can do it with data annotations??

```
[Display(Name = "Code Agence")]
[Required(ErrorMessage="Entrer un nombre de 4 chiffres")]
 public long CodeAgence { get; set; }
```

Comment: Use a regular expression attribute - `\d{4}`

Comment: like this :  [RegularExpression(@"^\d{1,15}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter up to 15 digits for a contact number")]

Comment: That works (except I thought you only wanted exactly 4 digits)?

Comment: Hhhh yeah i know.I will use it for many attributs.Thkns a lot Stephen Muecke